# Sqlachemy. How to query results a list of two models?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

there are models.

```
class CMiixin(objects):

    @declared_attr
    def x(cls):
        return Column(Float)


class ABase(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a_base'

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return {'polymorphic_identity': '%s' % cls.__tablename__,
                'polymorphic_on': cls.type,
                'with_polymorphic': '*'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key= True)
    type = Column(String)
    # other attr

class A(CMixin, ABase):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(ForeignKey('a_base.id'), primary_key= True)
    # other attr    

class BBase(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b_base'

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return {'polymorphic_identity': '%s' % cls.__tablename__,
                'polymorphic_on': cls.type,
                'with_polymorphic': '*'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key= True)
    type = Column(String)
    # other attr

class B(CMixin, ABase):
    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = Column(ForeignKey('b_base.id'), primary_key= True)
    # other attr
```

How to choose a single query A and B with x(attribute CMixin) <= 5?
something this
        db.session.query(???).filter(A.x <= 5, B.x <= 5).all()
        result list at A and B objects
Or is it impossible to do, and just add the
results of two queries?

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [union_all](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.union_all):

```
select1 = Session.query(A.x, <other_columns>).filter(A.x <= 5)
select2 = Session.query(B.x, <other_columns>).filter(B.x <= 5)
result = select1.union_all(select2).all()
```

UPDATE:

Just tested it on one of my apps:

```
engine = get_database_engine()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


qa = session.query(User.id).filter(User.id>=0)
print qa.all()  # prints [(3,), (4,)]

qb = session.query(Country.id).filter(Country.id>=0)
print qb.all()  # prints [(4,), (5,), (6,), (1,)]

print qa.union_all(qb).all()  # prints  [(3,), (4,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (1,)]

print qa.union_all(qb)
```

the actual query printed:

```
SELECT anon_1.user_id AS anon_1_user_id 
FROM (SELECT "user".id AS user_id 
      FROM "user" 
      WHERE "user".id >= %(id_1)s 

      UNION ALL 

      SELECT country.id AS country_id 
      FROM country 
      WHERE country.id >= %(id_2)s) AS anon_1
```

Comment: Should work, could you please provide how are you using this example and the resulting sql query?

Comment: Try to specify column names inside the `query()`, like I've described.

Comment: >>> qa = db.session.query(A.x).filter(A.x<=2)>> qa
    >>> qa.all()
    [(0,), (1,), (2,)]
    }>> qb = db.session.query(B.x).filter(B.x<=2)
    >>> qb.all()
    [(0,), (1,), (2,)]
    >>> qa.union(qb).all()
    [(0,), (2,), (1,)]
returns 3, not 6

Comment: Sorry, I'm with the phone, I can not normally
write code in the message

Comment: Edited the answer - it looks like you need `union_all`. Please, check.

Comment: so works, but if you return the object model,
not an attribute that does not work.
    qa=db.session.query(A).filter(A.x<=2)
    qb=db.session.query(B).filter(B.x<=2)
    qa.union_all(qb).all() 
result only A objects

Comment: Yeah, you have to pass columns explicitly in this case.